# Кратчайший путь до точки

Tags: алгоритм, математика, вычислительная-геометрия

Условие:

Дано `n` точек на координатной плоскости (x,y). Найти прямую, расстояние от любой точки до которой будет минимально.

Мое решение:

Я думаю, надо перебирать все точки на плоскости, строя из всех точек прямые, потом вычислять расстояние до каждой точки.  В правильном направлении я иду? Что-то мне кажется, что я не правильно думаю...

Comment: Поскольку точки не лежат на прямой все, здесь есть масса вариантов. Например, минимально максимальное расстояние от точки до прямой. Минимальна сумма расстояний от точек до прямой. Минимальна сумма квадратов расстояний. Что именно, какой критерий надо выбрать? И потом, при чем тут C++?

Comment: Минимальна сумма расстояний от точек до прямой.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что прямая не обязана проходить через 2 точки из набора, но пример пока не придумал.

Comment: Необязательно, чтобы прямая была из набора точек, это я свое мнение высказал по этому поводу, но я думаю, что-то не так

Comment: расстояние **от любой** точки - вы точно поняли задание? Там точно n точек?

Comment: @Шерзод Ёров: Ну так может нужно исправить текст вопроса, а не перекраивать его в комментариях?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если речь идёт о минимизации суммы расстояний от точек до прямой, то несложно показать, что такую прямую можно выбрать так, что она будет проходить через *одну* из заданных точек. А вот [здесь](http://theory.stanford.edu/~megiddo/pdf/leastdis.pdf) авторы показывают, что такую прямую можно выбрать проходящей через *две* точки исходного набора.

Тут уже можно предлагать "лобовой" алгоритм - перебирайте все пары точек и выбирайте лучшую из получившихся прямых. Перебор - квадратичен, проверка - еще сверху линейна, что дает нам O(n<sup>3</sup>) алгоритм.

По ссылке авторы предлагают свой O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) алгоритм. Вам решать, стоит ли овчинка выделки.